# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.CompilerInterface with PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

What can i do with this? I try to create bot for telegram with deploy on heroky. But i got this exception, when i Run my project. I using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. PlayFramework with sbt. Database - MongoDB

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xsbt.CompilerInterface
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:128)
sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:104)
sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:62)
sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:57)
sbt.compiler.CompilerCache$$anon$2.apply(CompilerCache.scala:47)
sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:45)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:50)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:74)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:49)
sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
sbt.compiler.IC$$anonfun$compileInternal$1.apply(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:66)
sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:64)
sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:32)
sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:72)
sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:71)
sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:99)
sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:71)
sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:155)
sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:141)
sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:886)
sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:877)
sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:875)
scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 10):

As often, restarting the IDE did the trick in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Delete .activator, .ivy2 and .sbt in your home directory and start again.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the .idea folder in the project and re-importing the sbt worked for me. (Deleting .ivy & .sbt in home folders did not).

Answer (score 3):

Invalidating cache helped. File -> Invalidate Caches...